# Integral with log and sin

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

So I have the following integral.
$$\int_0^{1} \frac{x^a-x^b}{\log x} \sin(\log x)\,\text{d}x. $$ I thought of a substitution like this $$\log x=t \implies (e^{a-1}-e^{b-1})\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-t}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,\text{d}t.$$
Is it correct? or am I missing something?

Comment: It would be more formal if you wrote your integral as a limit, and substituted then. Then there would be no space for a mistake.

Comment: You did made a mistake. $\int_{-\infty}^0 (e^{at}-e^{bt})\frac{\sin t}{t} \,\text{d}t$ would be more correct.

Comment: @Adam. May be you forgot the $dx$. Using exponential integral functions, this lead to an incredibly beautiful result.